# How to create a case object with caseNumber field in test method?

Tags: apex, unit-test, case

I need to create a case Object with case Number assigned to it in my test class

```
public static Case CreateCase(Id conId,Id accId){
    Case caseObj = new Case(
    ContactId = conID,
    AccountId = accId,
    Status = 'Working',
    Origin = 'Phone',
    CaseNumber = '11111111');
    return caseObj;     
}
```

But it throws error saying, caseNumber field is not writable.

I need to create a case object with CaseNumber field..is there any other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has typo error from "form" to "from" in a select statement:

```
Case caseObj = new Case(
    ContactId = conID,
    AccountId = accId,
    Status = 'Working',
    Origin = 'Phone');

insert caseObj;
caseObj = [select id, casenumber from case where id = : caseObj.id];
System.debug('case number' + caseObj.casenumber);
```

Comment: This is working..If i remove the select statement..it just returns null..Thanks for the clarification. I thought just `insert caseObj` would be sufficient.

Comment: Clarification: DML operations only update ID value of the object. To get back all new changes, you have to query the record again.

Answer (score 3):

As CaseNumber is of the type "Auto Number", it doesn't allow us to write/assign a value to that field.

Comment: so is there a way I can create a case object for test purpose?? For now i am using the cases already created but I want to create case objects in the test method instead of  using the already created.

Comment: Yes, you can create case records in test class methods without specifying Case number. On case creation, salesforce would auto-generate case number for newly created cases.

Comment: @Anshul No, it is not assigning the caseNumber for the case objects created in test methods. For contacts object also Name field is empty.

Comment: Did you try by re-querying your case record (after creation). In case of autonumber / formula fields, they would not be automatically set on creation (for the object in apex) and needs to be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to set the formula or auto number field in the test method even without inserting the record.

**Define the below method somewhere:**

```
public static SObject setFormulaOrAutoNumberField(SObject salesforceObject, Map<String , Object> fieldNameAndValueMap){
String jsonString = JSON.serialize(salesforceObject);
Map<String, Object> dataMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);
for(String fieldName : fieldNameAndValueMap.keySet()){
  dataMap.put(fieldName, fieldNameAndValueMap.get(fieldName));
}
jsonString = JSON.serialize(dataMap);
return (SObject)JSON.deserialize(jsonString, SObject.class);
```

}

**Use the above method like:**

```
Case theCase = new Case();
theCase = (Case)setFormulaOrAutoNumberField(theCase, new Map<String, Object>{'CaseNumber' => 'C-12345678'});
```